# Rutherford Model of Atom

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics

When finding the closest distance of approach of helium nucleus to the gold atom, we apply TME conservation. But the alpha particle is accelerated and hence, emits radiations. Why don't we consider these emitted radiations' energies and also, any magnetic field?

Comment: The energy lost to radiation is negligible compared to the other energies in the problem.

Comment: Bremsstrahlung is certainly a thing for electrons, but for an alpha particle, nearly 8000 times more massive than an electron, it isn't particularly an issue.